# Insert statement conflicted with foreign key EF Core many to many

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

[image]

[image]

Service:

```
 public Cart AddProductToCart(Product product, Cart cart)
        {
            CartProduct cartProduct = new CartProduct();
            cartProduct.CartId = cart.Id;
            cartProduct.ProductId = product.Id;

            _dbContexet.CartProduct.Add(cartProduct);
            _dbContexet.SaveChanges();
            return cart;
        }
```

I have a cart that can have many product and product that can have many carts, 1 cart belongs to 1 user...
When i try to insert this product and cart i get this error:

```
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CartProduct_Carts_ProductId". The conflict occurred in database "ManagerZ", table "dbo.Carts", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated
```

.

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with **dbo.Carts.Id** column. Try to debug check which Id is being passed and if it actually *exists* in the table

Comment: Is cart already exists  in database or you are adding cart in the same request

Comment: This error is indicating that the cartid you are trying to insert does not exist in cart table

Comment: Something looks like it might be messed up with your FK. `FK_CartProduct_Carts_ProductId` implies it should be referencing the `Id` column on `Product` but the error is complaining about the `Id` column on `Cart`. It would seem like your FK is accidentally mapped to the Cart table instead of the Product table. You pass in a ProductID that doesn't have a row with the same ID in Carts and the FK constraint will trip because it is looking at the wrong table.